# Angular: 'translate' pipe not working in another Module

Tags: angular

I have created a I18nModule:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
  ],
  exports: [TranslateModule]
})
export class I18nModule {

}
```

I have created also an TranslationService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TranslationService {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}

  init(): void {
    // Retrieve the selected language from session storage, if it exists
    const storedLang = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedLang');
    // Add supported languages and their translation files
    this.translate.addLangs(['en', 'it']);
    this.translate.use(storedLang ? storedLang : 'en'); // Set default language if none is stored 
  }

  setLanguage(lang: string): void {
    this.translate.use(lang); // Switch the language
  }

  getLanguages(): string[]{
    return this.translate.getLangs();
  }
}
```

I also provide the Service in providers array in App.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [TranslationService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private translationService: TranslationService) {
    this.translationService.init(); // Initialize the translation service
  }
}
```

I have successfully translated one label in the navbar component (which is associated with components.module.ts that is imported in app.module.ts), where I also injected the TranslationService to create a button to switch the language.

All good till now, but I have another module, named tables.module.ts, in which I have the component NgxDatatablesComponent where I want to put a label in, in order to be translated.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [NgxDatatablesComponent, SortableComponent, TablesComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(TablesRoutes),
    NgxDatatableModule,
    ProgressbarModule.forRoot(),
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    PaginationModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
    NgxPrintModule,
    I18nModule
  ]
})
export class TablesModule {}
```

I have imported the I18nModule in TablesModule, like I did in ComponentsModule, the 'translate' pipe is founded, but is not translating anything.
I have to mention that there is no problem with .json, there is no typo or something like that.

Any suggestions on why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now `I18nModule` and `TranslationService` both are independent.

`TranslationService` is injected in the root module.

`I18nModule` is imported in the `ComponentsModule`

`I18nModule` is also imported in the `TablesModule`

If you want to `TranslationService` to be available in the `TablesModule`, either use

`providers: [TranslationService],` in `I18nModule` so that any `module` that imports `I18nModule` `TranslationService` would be available as providers.

Or a naive approach to add

`providers: [TranslationService],` in `TablesModule`

Comment: Thank you sir, that was the problem, but I am a bit confused, since in ComponentsModule it is working, and in TablesModule it is not. I have done the same thing to both of them. The only difference was that, the TablesModule was not imported in App.module.ts

Comment: EDIT:
I provide the service inside the I18nModule, right now is translating, but I have to refresh the page, whereas in navbar component, the label is getting translated without refreshing the page. Any suggestions?